# How can I update table view from another view controller with out segues in swift 3?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, viewcontroller

How can I update table view from another view controller in tabbed application project  when something is finish like I download videos from the Internet. I need when this download is finish the table view in the another view controller update auto, I try to make it but I couldn't.

The following is my code:

```
let getControllers = self.parent?.tabBarController?.customizableViewControllers
let navigationController = getControllers?[2] as! UINavigationController
let videoViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! VideoFolderListViewController
 videoViewController.tableView.reloadData()
```

But this is not working, I don't know and not update the table view.

Please help me

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Can you please define "this is not working"? Are you getting any crash or error?

Comment: No crash the app is retyrn to me the instance from the view controller but this view controller can' t call table view i don't know why

Comment: You cannot update UI directly from outside of the View Controller you have to use NotificationCenter or Protocol defination

Comment: Have you any example on how can i update tabe view from another view controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NotificationCenter like this:

```
class FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    func someAction (){
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UPDATED_DATA"), object: nil) // post updated data
    }

}


class TableViewController : UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(updated_data),
                                               name:Notification.Name("UPDATED_DATA"),
                                               object: nil)//register for notification
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func updated_data(notification:Notification) -> Void{
        tableView.reloadData() // update data here
    }
}
```